# How to apply CSS class to slides with Swiper Slider?

Tags: slider, carousel, swiper.js

I would like to add transitions and CSS animations when my Swiper is playing

I want to have an animation when entering slide, another one when leaving (for example with translating and fading texts/buttons)

How to do that? Is it difficult ?

Can you explain me with a simple example ?